# В каких случаях стоит создавать несколько ответов на вопрос?

Tags: обсуждение, правила, ответы

Правильно ли я понимаю, что если у задачи есть несколько способов решения, то лучше создать несколько ответов для каждого варианта, а не один, включающий все?

Например, мой вопрос [Как поддерживать равенство высоты двух элементов textarea?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/484089/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-textarea)
Я решил, что нужно разбить решения на два ответа, так как это даёт возможность выбрать лучшее решение и упрощает голосование.

Правильно ли я сделал? Не расходится ли это с какими-либо правилами? Когда *стоит* разбивать ответ на несколько, а в каких случаях лучше изложить всё в одном?

Answer (score 10):

Если ответы достаточно разные, то давайте их отдельно. Если всего-лишь вариации на тему - стоит объединять.

*Более точный ответ дать сложно, т.к. вопрос весьма абстрактный.*

Comment: Какой-то размытый совет, по-моему. Но, наверное, конкретизировать действительно сложно.

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev вы можете написать свой вариант, посмотреть сколько человек с ним согласится и какие комментарии они дадут

Comment: С вашим ответом я согласен, я и выразил сомнение, что вряд ли можно сильно его конкретизировать.

Answer (score 6):

Если ответы это просто разные решения *одной и той же* задачи **и** хочется (на усмотрение отвечающего) чтобы была возможно оценить их полезность (проголосовать) отдельно, то можно отдельные ответы создавать.

Не стоит разбивать один ответ, который содержит несколько решений, если нет необходимости ранжировать решения с помощью голосования. Например, если ответ содержит разные решения только потому что они адаптированы под разные разновидности исходной задачи (то есть если фактически разные задачи решаются -- разные интерпретации вопроса). Или же если только одно решение в ответе явно является более предпочтительным, а другие имеют подчинённую роль, например, чтобы лучше объяснить или проиллюстрировать что не надо делать. Или же если ответ явно описывает/сравнивает достоинства и недостатки нескольких подходов.

Нужно думать о читателях: идеально, должно быть достаточно прочитать только один (принятый) ответ, чтобы найти решение. Если ответы не являются самодостаточными, их следует объединить.

[What is the official etiquette on answering a question twice?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25209/137096)

Answer (score 3):

я думаю, что выбор — публиковать разные варианты решения (или ответы на разные части вопроса) в одном ответе, или создавать несколько ответов — лежит исключительно на отвечающем.

каких-либо правил по этому поводу, насколько мне известно, нет (по крайней мере, на [ru.so](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)).

руководствоваться же отвечающему, как мне представляется, следует исключительно здравым смыслом.

Comment: Если в ответе 2 принципиально разных ответа (например, раскрывающие разные подходы к решению), то автор наказывает сам себя, ведь он мог бы получить плюсов за 2 ответа в 2 раза больше чем за один

Comment: @KromStern, это соображение никак не может влиять на отношение сообщества к выбору отвечающего — разбивать ли многовариантный ответ на части. данный выбор остаётся за ним (отвечающим).

Comment: Не так вас прочитал, отбой )